# Call function from enumeration

Tags: java, android, function, enumeration

I have enumeration in JAVA code `ERequestTypes` my enumeration contains more then 20 elements, every element is a name of a function in my JAVA code. Now I want do following thing instead of writing `switch(ERequestTypes) case` and in the cases calling function in this way:

```
switch(ERequestTypes a) {
    case ERequestTypes.Initialize:
        Initialize();
    case ERequestTypes.Uninitialize:
        Uninitialize();
}
```

I want to do it with one line. All the functions in the enum have same argument and return same int value. How I can do that ? may be keep pointers of functions in enum like in C++ or something else. Please help !

```
class CRequestValue {
    /**
     * Constructor.
     * 
     * @param aName - Name of the request.
     * @param aCode - Code of the request.
     */
    public CRequestValue(String aName, int aCode) {
        this.mName = aName;
        this.mCode = aCode;
    }

    private String mName;
    private int    mCode;

    public String GetName() {
        return this.mName;
    }

    public int GetCode() {
        return this.mCode;
    }

} /* class CRequestValue **/

enum ERequestTypes
{
    Initialize(new CRequestValue("Initialize", 0)),
    Uninitialize(new CRequestValue("Uninitialize", 1)),
    GetDeviceInfoList(new CRequestValue("GetDeviceInfoList", 2)),
    GetDeviceInfo(new CRequestValue("GetDeviceInfo", 3));

    private CRequestValue mRequestValue;

    private ERequestTypes(CRequestValue aRequestValue) {
        this.mRequestValue = aRequestValue;
    }

    public String GetName() {
        return this.mRequestValue.GetName();
    }

    public int GetCode() {
        return this.mRequestValue.GetCode();
    }

} /* enum ERequestTypes **/
```

Comment: Why would you want to arrange functions in an enum? What is the goal of your design-pattern?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for [reflection](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/ALT/Reflection/).

```
ErequestTypes a = <init>;
Object o = Class.forName(<your class name>).getMethod(a.getName(), <argtype>.class).invoke(<instance of your class, or null if static method>, <arg>);
```

Note that the Class.forName is not required if you already know what class the methods are in.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what is your goal, but you could use polimorphism instead of switch block, for example:

```
interface Invokable {
    int init(Object arg);
    int uninit(Object arg);
}

enum Request {
    INIT() {
        @Override
        public int invoke(Invokable invokable, Object arg) {
            return invokable.init(arg);
        }
    },
    UNINIT() {
        @Override
        public int invoke(Invokable invokable, Object arg) {
            return invokable.uninit(arg);
        }
    },
    ;
    public abstract int invoke(Invokable invokable, Object arg);
}


Invokable i = ....;
Object arg = ....;
Request r = Request.INIT;
r.invoke(i, arg); // should invoke Invokable.init(arg);
r = Request.UNINIT;
r.invoke(i, arg); // should invoke Invokable.uninit(arg);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could go with the polymorphism that Pavel mentioned, but there is another solution--you don't really need an enum at all.

It's quite simple to make each function it's own object and just pass around/use instances of those objects as you would the enums themselves.

There are also a few solutions using Anonymous inner classes (Attaching them to object instances and passing those instances around), but I don't think that is generally as reusable as just making separate objects.

Here is some fake code:

```
public void MainClass {
    private final Runnable init=new Runnable {
        run() {
            // Initialize the system
        }
    }
    private final Runnable uninit = new Runnable() {
        run() {
            // Uninitialize the system
        }
    }

public someMethod() {

    // At this point you can treat the instances as you would any variable...
    Runnable nextOperation = init;

    // and executing whichever one you have is as simple as:
    nextOperation.run();
```

If you wish for "Type Safety" (as with enums) don't extend Runnable but create a new class that extends runnable then extend that class.

Since these are "inner classes" (Defined inside the context of another class) they can access and modify all that classes member variables making them more like independant methods than stand-alone classes.

Finally notice that since each class is defined in-line anonymously they are almost as hard to create "Duplicates" as enums, so you can generally treat them exactly as enums (for instance, using "==" instead of .equals().